# Are my calculations about WOTS parameters correct?

Tags: hash, post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

I'm reading the WOTS+ paper, but I'm having some trouble with its notation and specially the involved units. For example, under my interpretation, the parameters `n=11`, `w=16` and `m=256` result in a quantum security level of about `81` bits, with a `992 bytes` signature length, but that looks incorrect.

To the best of my knowledge, I've made the following script to output public key and signature lengths, and security level, for both WOTS+ and WOTS.

### WOTS+

```
import math

n = 16  # security parameter, in bytes
w = 16  # w parameter
m = 256 # message length, in bits

l1 = math.ceil(m / math.log2(w))
l2 = math.floor(math.log2(l1*(w-1))/math.log2(w))+1
l  = l1 + l2

# formulas from the paper
pub_len = (l + w - 1) * n + 8        # public key length in bytes
sig_len = l * n                      # signature length in bytes
sec_lvl = n*8 - math.log2(w*w*l + w) # quantum security level in bits

print("wots+")
print("pub_len: " + str(pub_len))
print("sig_len: " + str(sig_len))
print("sec_lvl: " + str(sec_lvl))
```

### WOTS

```
import math

n = 256 # security parameter, in bits
w = 16  # bits per signing unit
m = 256 # message length, in bits

l1 = n / w
l2 = math.ceil((math.floor(math.log2(l1))+1+w)/w)
l  = l1 + l2

# probably wrong
pub_len = m * l1 / 8 # public key length in bytes
sig_len = m * l / 8  # signature length in bytes
sec_lvl = m / 3      # quantum security level in bits

print("wots")
print("pub_len: " + str(pub_len))
print("sig_len: " + str(sig_len))
print("sec_lvl: " + str(sec_lvl))
```

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "80 bits of postquantum security"?  Do you mean taking $2^{80}$ operations on a quantum computer?  If so, you need to take into account Grover's, which is somewhat difficult to quantify - a naïve application would assume a 160 bit hash; however Grover's would require $2^{80}$ successive hash computations to find a 160 bit preimage with $2^{80}$ computation, which is unrealistic...

Comment: @poncho yes, I mean taking 2^80 operations on a quantum computer. To be honest I'd just like to make sure I understand the formulas in the paper. I've updated the question to ask that more directly.

Answer (score 1):

The WOTS+ calculations are largely correct. Only the security level is "just" the security against conventional adversaries. The right equation for quantum adversaries should be

```
sec_lvl = n*8/2 - math.log2(w*w*l + w) # quantum security level in bits
```

As quantum computers can find preimages and second preimages with $2^{8n/2}$ queries.

In the WOTS calculations

```
pub_len = m * l1 / 8 # public key length in bytes 
sig_len = m * l / 8 # signature length in bytes
```

should be

```
pub_len = n * l # public key length in bytes 
sig_len = n * l # signature length in bytes
```

(signatures, secret and public keys consist of l chain values which have n bits).

Otherwise, things seem to be correct.